# URL amigável cujo ID é o título da notícia

Tags: php, url-amigável

Estou a  tentar implementar no sistema de rotas um alias que quero, seja proveniente da base de dados. Vamos imaginar um portal de noticias onde na tabela da bd tenho a tabela "noticias" onde é carregada uma url propria para cada noticia para que a url fique algo como "http://www.omeusite.com/o-titulo-da-minha-noticia/".
Qual é a melhor forma de fazer isso???

Ao invés de usar o ID numérico, gostaria de usar o título da notícia somente.

Comment: Você quer saber "*qual é a melhor forma de fazer isso*" ou "*de que forma dá para fazer isso*"?

Answer (score -2):

O caminho mais fácil a ser seguido no seu caso, é utilizar reescrita de url no arquivo .htaccess.

## O que é um arquivo .htaccess?

Os arquivos .htaccess são arquivos de acesso e configuração do Apache, são arquivos lidos pelo Apache toda vez que você tenta acessar um arquivo que esta dentro de uma pasta (ou sub pastas) onde exista um arquivo .htaccess. Nesse arquivo podemos criar regras de bloqueio de acesso, redirecionamentos e reescritas de URL.

### Exemplo

```
# redirect "/section.php?id=xxx" to "/section/xxx"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/section\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /section/%1? [R=301,L]

# internally rewrite "/section/xxx" to "/section.php?id=xxx"
RewriteRule ^section/([0-9]+)$ /section.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Para se aprofundar melhor no assunto siga esse passo a passo, é muito simples de implementar! http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis